# Let T be a linear operator of an n-dimensional vector space V over a field F. Assume that T is nilpotent. Show that $T^n = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear operator of an n-dimensional vector space V over a field F. Assume that T is nilpotent. Show that $T^n = 0$.

I've seen people prove this with an argument involving minimal polynomials. Can someone prove this without such an argument?

Comment: They're looking to prove that the degree of nilpotency is bounded by the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T^n \ne 0$. Then there exists $x\ne 0$ such that $T^n x \ne 0$. Hence, 
$\{ x,Tx,T^2x,\cdots,T^n x\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors. To see why, suppose
$$
         \alpha_0 x+\alpha_1 Tx+\cdots + \alpha_n T^n x = 0,
$$

and apply $T^k$ to the above, where $T^kx\ne 0$ and $T^{k+1}x=0$. Conclude that $\alpha_0=0$. Continue in orer to conclude that $\alpha_0=\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$. Hence $\{x,Tx,T^2x,\cdots,T^nx\}$ is a linearly-independent set, which forces $n < \dim{V}$. This is true for every $x$. Therefore $T^{\dim(V)}=0$.

Comment: What is $k$ and why is $T^k x \neq 0$?

Comment: @user193319: Since $T$ is nilpotent, there is some m such that $T^m=0$. Take k to be the maximum positive integer such that $T^k x\ne 0$. By this choice of k, $T^{k+i}x=0$ for all $i\ge 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Note first that if $T$ fixes any nonzero $W\subset V$, then $T(W)< W$; otherwise, $T\vert W$ is an isomorphism, and so $T^k\not = 0$ for all $k$. Now consider the chain of inclusions $V\supset T(V) \supset T^2(V) \supset \cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subspaces $V_i:=\text{Im}(T^i)$. If $V_i=V_{i+1}$, then by definition $V_i=V_j,\forall j\ge i$. Since $T$ si nilpotent, $V_i$ is descending to $\left\{0\right\}$. Thus if $V_i=V_{i+1}$ for some $i$, then $V_i=\left\{0\right\}$. Also if $V_i\ne V_{i+1}$ then $\text{dim}(V_i)\ge\text{dim}(V_{i+1})+1$. As a consequence $V_n=\left\{0\right\}$.

Also, one can use the pigeon-hole principle: the dimensions of $V_i$ are in the set $\left\{1,2,\cdots,n\right\}$, and there are $n+1$ elements in $\left\{\text{dim}(V_i)\mid i=0,1,\cdots,n\right\}$, so $\text{dim}(V_i)=\text{dim}(V_{i+1})$ for some $i=0,1,\cdots,n$, which implies our desired result as $V_i\supseteq V_{i+1},\forall i$.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For a more computational approach, every matrix can be upper triangularized.  It suffices to prove that if $g$ is a nilpotent $n$ by $n$ upper triangular matrix, then $g^n = 0$.  You can check that all the diagonal entries of $g$ are zero, and then the claim easily follows.